# Change word color and counter with each click Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have white text in 10 divs that should become blue once the user clicks on them and the total number of "selected" divs is 5. I did it like this:

```
<div id="sen1" class="sentences">Text1</div>
<div id="sen2" class="sentences">Text2</div>        
<div id="sen3" class="sentences">Text1</div>
<div id="sen4" class="sentences">Text2</div>        
...

$(".sentences").click(function() {
    count++
    $(this).css("color", "blue")
    selected_true.push($(this).text())
    if (count == 5){
        $(".sentences").off("click")
        //go to next page
    }
});
```

Now I want the text to become white again if a blue text is clicked again and want to decrease the `count` variable by one. So ideally I want to increase the counter each time a sentence is selected and decrease it again once it is un-selected.
I thought about `toggle` but how would I incorporate the counter in the toggle method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing it this way might make more sense:

css

```
.sentences {
   color: #fff;
}
.sentences.turnedon { 
   color: blue;
}
```

javascript

```
$(".sentences").click(function() {

    if( $(this).hasClass('turnedon') ) {

       $(this).removeClass('turnedon');
       count-1;

    } else {

       $(this).addClass('turnedon');
       count++;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to add a class to each clicked div and remove it when it is clicked again.

Use the JQuery [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to get it done in one simple line:

```
$(this).toggleClass('selected');
```

Then you can count the selected divs like so:

```
$('.selected').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using 2 classes. If you have 2 styles classes you can use.

```
 $('yourSeletor').toggleClass('yourClassBlue');
```

See this example: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass